# Using GAC assemblies needs permissions

Tags: c#, assemblies, .net-assembly, gac, gacutil

I just installed two libraries on GAC and I'm trying to use them in a simple application where I only call the constructor of my method:

```
  MyMethod m = new MyMethod();
```

When I try to run the `.exe` of my app, I can see it in the task manager processes, but it  doesn't load.

If I elevate permissions of the executable, then the simple app **appears on task manager, and also loads**. But, why is it that I need to give administrator permissions to an application that consumes GAC assemblies? It's the first time it happens to me.

How can I consume a GAC assembly without asking for administrator permissions?

I think I have GAC permissions to read, as I can read the older version, but not the newer one...

**EDIT:** **I realized that, if I stay for some minutes, the `.dll` is consumed and the application runs. But everytime I need an assembly that I installed on GAC, has a really big delay.** **Any idea on why?**

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I didn't say which library is it because it is called **UserControlLibrary.dll**, I developed it. And there are older versions of my library that are used on some of my older projects.

To use the new one, I published a policy that redirects from the old version of the assembly to the new one.

**NOTE:** Usage of the older version works fine. Usage of the new one, doesn't work (after redirection).

Comment: Why negative votes and not explaining why? I have a really important problem, and I will thank a lot at least that people explain that negatives votes, so I can improve my question an, fortunately, somebody can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific about which assemblies and what your code is trying to do?...

Giving admin privelidges is kind of a catchall... there's more likely a certain permission required that you have not provided...

e.g. here's a little ditty about the same issue for [SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/07/15/specifying-global-assembly-cache-permissions.aspx) where the SSRSSvcAccount account did not have read permission for the GAC, which was solved using

```
cacls.exe %windir%/assembly /e /t /p DOMAIN\SSRSSvcAccount:R
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I can read from GAC, but my app remains at background on TaskManager if not run as administrator, but not loading.

Comment: How did you install it into the GAC? Have you looked at the ACL; the systemroot directory is often protected using an access control list (ACL) to control write and execute access. Because the global assembly cache is installed in a subdirectory of the systemroot directory, it inherits that directory's ACL.

Comment: I install it using WiX, publishing it as an Assembly=".net"

Comment: hmmm... where does the dll reside? is it in a trusted zone?